# How to pass token to backend API's in API-Umbrella

Tags: api, jwt, umbrella

We have implemented Micro-Service Architecture for our API development and I am using API Umbrella as the gateway for all the micro-services. All the api's in the micro-service are using JWT token authentication mechanism for authentication and authorization. And I am not sure how to pass JWT tokens to back-end API's through API Umbrella Gateway. Any help here is highly appreciated.

https://api-umbrella.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/api-backends/http-headers.html

As per the above documentation, I am unable to find a way to pass the JWT tokens to back-end api's.

Answer (score 0):

*All the api's in the micro-service are using JWT token authentication mechanism for authentication and authorization.*

I guess this approach doesn't fit to the API-Gateway/Micro-Service architecture. A large advantage of using API-Gateways is, that the micro-services behind doesn't need to care about things like `authentication`, `authorization`, `monitoring` etc.
This all should be taken over by the API-Gateway.